# React Native setState(…) warning with both componentWillMount and componentDidMount

Tags: react-native

I'm starting with react-native and in my project I got to a point where everything works but there's this warning:

`Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component.`

So, I've looked several QA, tried a few solutions(changing the `setState()` call from `componentWillMount` and `componentDidMount`) but... the warning is always there.

Here is part of the code:

```
REQUEST_URL = 'http://url/users.php';

(...)

module.exports = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            uid: null,
            bid: null,
            username: null,
        }
    },

    componentDidMount: function() {
        this.fetchData();
    },
    fetchData: function() {
        fetch(REQUEST_URL)
            .then( (response) => response.json() )
            .then( (json) => {
                console.log('setState called');
                this.setState({
                    uid: json.users[0].user_id,
                    bid: json.users[0].building_id,
                    username: json.users[0].username
                });
            })
            .done();
    },
    render: function() {
        if (!this.state.uid) { //user is not defined
            console.log('not rendered');
            return <Text>chargement...</Text>
        }
        // else
        console.log('rendered');
        var userId = this.state.uid;
        var buildingId = this.state.bid;
        var username = this.state.username;

        return (
            <View style={styles.content}>
                <Text style={styles.label}>User Id</Text>
                <Text>{userId}</Text>

                <Text style={styles.label}>Building Id</Text>
                <Text>{buildingId}</Text>

                <Text style={styles.label}>Username</Text>
                <Text>{username}</Text>
            </View>
        )
    },
});
```

The `users.php` returns a json content-type.

Any clues?

Thanx.

Comment: Is it possible, that you dismount your component before the network call returns?

Comment: this is a route called in a `immediatelyResetRouteStack() ` could that be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem may be that react re-mounts certain components multiple times in one render (think that has something to do with the representation of initial values, could not find the question here), therefore your `state` would be set to a component that is not mounted.

If you set your `state` in a decoupled timeout that can be cleared when the component unmounts, you avoid setting state on a unmounted component.

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.mounted = true;
  // this.fetchTimeout = setTimeout(()=>{
    this.fetchData();
  // });
},
componentWillUnmount() {
  // clearTimeouts(this.fetchTimeout);
  this.mounted = false;
},
fetchData() {
    fetch(REQUEST_URL)
        .then( (response) => response.json() )
        .then( (json) => {
            console.log('setState called');
            if (this.mounted === true){
               this.setState({
                  uid: json.users[0].user_id,
                  bid: json.users[0].building_id,
                  username: json.users[0].username
              });
            }
        })
        .done();
},
```

I still don't know if we are supposed to use `TimerMixins` but this way works without those. 
(`TimerMixins` take care of clearing any timeout or interval set in the component)

EDIT: update sample to only call `setState` of the component is still mounted.
I do not know if there is a better way, but as far as I know until now you can not cancel a fetch request.

Comment: ah yeah, the fetch request is not terminated. 
I will update my answer with a new proposal

Comment: It works, I've just gorgot to comment the code like you did. Thanx once again @schinknbrot